# Como criar amostras numéricas baseado em múltiplas condições em múltiplos vetores?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Dado o seguinte data frame:

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~pass_id, ~km_ini, ~km_fin,
        1L,    0.89,    2.39,
        2L,    1.53,    3.03,
        3L,    21.9,    23.4,
        4L,    23.4,    24.9,
        5L,      24,    25.5,
        6L,    25.9,    27.4,
        7L,    36.7,    38.2,
        8L,    41.4,    42.9,
        9L,    42.1,    43.6,
       10L,    45.5,      47
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Eu preciso de uma amostra de 50 números que preencham os seguintes critérios para o data frame como um todo, não apenas para cada linha dele:

1. `>= .750`
2. `<= 99.450`
3. `< km_ini - .750`
4. `> km_fin + .750`

O que eu consegui até agora é a parte mais fácil, que são as duas primeiras (que eu poderia fazer diretamente a partir do próprio sorteio com `runif` - mérito 0). O problema é que depois empaquei, tentei fazer um `enframe` e depois tentei `filter`, sem sucesso.

P.S.: eu não necessariamente preciso do resultado como data frame, pode ser um vetor.

```r
library(tidyverse, verbose = F)

set.seed(42)
sort(runif(100000, 0, 99.450)) %>% 
  enframe(., "ID", "km") %>% 
  filter(km >= .750 & km <= 99.450 - .750)
#> # A tibble: 98,467 x 2
#>       ID    km
#>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1   763 0.750
#>  2   764 0.751
#>  3   765 0.751
#>  4   766 0.753
#>  5   767 0.753
#>  6   768 0.754
#>  7   769 0.754
#>  8   770 0.755
#>  9   771 0.755
#> 10   772 0.757
#> # … with 98,457 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**EDIT: tentando representar visualmente o problema**

O resultado final necessita ser um conjunto numérico que avalie todo o conjunto de dados, não apenas cada linha separadamente. Como exemplo para as primeiras duas linha, veja a seguinte representação:

[image: Representação esquemática]

Desta forma, veja que:

- A linha preta indica que não posso ter dados menores que .750.
- A linha azul indica onde não posso ter registros em função da área de abrangência do `km_ini` e `km_fin` (flechas) da linha 1 e mais um apêndice considerando a área de + ou - .750 (entre as flechas e os pontos).
- A linha vermelha indica onde não posso ter registros em função da área de abrangência do `km_ini` e `km_fin` (flechas) da linha 2 e mais um apêndice considerando a área de + ou - .750 (entre as flechas e os pontos).

Desta forma, já de cara, o conjunto aleatório de dados, dentro dos 4000 primeiros metros, só poderia ter números a partir de `3030 + 750`.

A questão, então, é tentar fazer isso programaticamente de forma que todas as linhas do data frame sejam avaliadas e os números gerados não estejam dentro de todas as condições citadas.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se percebi a pergunta mas se quer `n = 50` números aleatórios descritos depois da última edição da pergunta talvez o seguinte código resolva o problema.

1. Calcula os valores mínimos e máximos descritos acima.
2. Cria uma tabela com `n` linhas, escolhendo aleatoriamente quais as linhas a replicar.
3. Gera números aleatórios `km` dentro dos limites calculados.
4. Descarta as colunas auxiliares criadas.

Se precisar só dos números gerados, pode ainda terminar com um pipe `%>%` para `select(km)`.

```
library(tidyverse, verbose = FALSE)

set.seed(42)

n <- 50

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Min = pmax(km_ini - 0.750, 0.750),
         Max = pmin(km_fin + 0.750, 99.450)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(tibble(pass_id = sample(.$pass_id, n, TRUE)), by = "pass_id") %>%
  mutate(km = if_else(Min >= 0.750, runif(n(), max(Max), 99.450), runif(n(), 0.750, min(Min)))) %>%
  select(-Min, -Max)
## A tibble: 50 x 4
#   pass_id km_ini km_fin    km
#     <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1       1   0.89   2.39  77.0
# 2       1   0.89   2.39  91.7
# 3       1   0.89   2.39  57.5
# 4       1   0.89   2.39  61.8
# 5       1   0.89   2.39  90.6
# 6       2   1.53   3.03  83.6
# 7       2   1.53   3.03  60.2
# 8       2   1.53   3.03  50.0
# 9       2   1.53   3.03  55.0
#10       2   1.53   3.03  58.9
## … with 40 more rows
```

Comment: Agradeço muito o auxílio, talvez eu não tenha feito a pergunta da forma mais correta (como melhorar?).

Veja bem, o resultado na coluna `km` não me atender porque ela pega critérios de algumas linhas do `df` original, mas não de todo `df`. Assim, peguemos, por exemplo, a linha 8 do resultado do seu exemplo. Ela aponta um valor de 2.54. Todavia, 2.54 não é .750 menor do que o km_ini seguinte, que é 1.53. Dessa forma, esse valor não me atende. Mesmo o valor da linha 7 (.413) não me atende porque ele não é .750 menor do que .89 e nem é também maior do que .750 (item 1 da lista de requisitos).

Comment: @rdornas Eu percebi que para cada linha o valor aleatório deveria estar entre `km_ini - 0.750` e `km_fin + 0.750`, daí o `runif` ter esses limites.

Comment: @rdornas De facto não é maior que 0.750 (condição 1). Então, na linha 8 deveria ser entre `max(km_ini - 0.750, 0.750)` e `min(km_fin + 0.750, 3.14)`, ou não? Estes limites do intervalo são `0.750` e `3.14`.

Comment: Acho que sua abordagem está correta, o caminho talvez seja por aí. A questão é que o número que eu preciso tem que estar contemplado para o `df` como um todo. Pense realmente em trechos de uma rodovia, em que nenhum dos números aleatórios pode estar dentro de qualquer intervalo entre `km_ini` e `km_fim` (e nem a 750 m antes do km_ini, nem a 750 m depois do  km_fim) em todo o data frame. Nessas condições, em alguns km há sobreposição, o que dificulta a resolução do problema. Agradeço muito a ajuda e a discussão!

Comment: @rdornas Acho que desta está. Veja agora.

Comment: É incrível como algo simples possa ser tão complexo. Infelizmente não chegamos à resposta. Por exemplo, na linha 1, .829 não é verdadeiro na condição `km_ini - .750`. Na realidade, nesse pequeno excerto do resultado que enviou, não há nenhum resultado que seja `km_ini < km_ini - 750` ou `km_fin > km_fin + 750`. No fim das contas, veja que eu não posso ter nenhum número menor do que 2.39 (que é o primeiro km_fin), porque na linha 1, por exemplo, `.89 - .750 = .14`, mas a condição 1 diz que tem que ser `>750` e entre km_ini e km_fin também não posso ter números. Peço desculpas pelo trabalho!

Comment: @rdornas Linha 1: `km` tem sempre que ser `>.75` e `km_ini - .75 = .14` logo o `liminf = .75` e `km_ini = .89`. Do lado de cima, `km` tem de ser `<99.45` e `km_fin+.75=3.14` logo `limsup = 3.14` e `km_fin=2.39`. Então o número aleatório `km` está **ou** em `[.75, .89]` **ou** em `[2.39, 3.14]`. É assim que eu estou a perceber o problema. Isto está certo? (Pelos vistos não.) Quando diz que *"não há nenhum resultado que seja `km_ini < km_ini - 750` ou `km_fin > km_fin + 750`"* é evidente que não, eliminando `km_ini`de ambos os lados daria `0 < -.75` e o mesmo para `km_fin`.

Comment: Rui, fiz uma nova edição da pergunta. Coloquei uma ilustração para tentar mostrar de forma mais visual o problema. Talvez fique um pouco mais claro. Se tiver dúvidas, não hesite em questionar.